# IMO Hong Kong TST 2014

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $m,n$ be distinct positive integer not exceeding 2013 and $d$ be their gcd. Suppose $d^2|3(m-n)$. Find the greatest possible value of $d(m+n)$.

I only know $m-n$ should be a perfect square, but then i dont have much idea, please helps.

Comment: $m-n$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: I assume you mean the competition that occurred in 2013, rather than the one to occur next year?

Comment: $\{m,n\}=\{414,2001\}$ , $\max=166,635$.

Comment: The key seems to be equating $d^2$ with $3(m-n)$.

Comment: Which is the same as saying that $d(m+n)$ is maximum when $\displaystyle\frac{3(m-n)}{d^2}$ is minimum.

Comment: @dfeuer, TST 2014 means "team selection test" for the 2014 IMO, which in some countries includes tests given in 2013.

Answer (score 3):

I let $m = da$ and $n = db$.  Since $d = \gcd(m,n)$, $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.  Without loss of generality, $m>n$, so that $a>b$.

First suppose that $3\! \not | \ d$.  Then $d^2 | (m-n) = d(a-b)$, or equivalently $d | (a-b)$.  We want $d(m+n) = d^2(a+b)$.  For fixed $a$, we cannot do worse than to increase $b$ all the way to $a-d$.  Thus we want to maximize $d^2(2a-d) = 2ad^2 - d^3$ under the condition that $a \geq d+1$ and $ad \leq 2013$.  For fixed $d$, we might as well increase $a$ until $\lfloor \frac{2013}d \rfloor$.

To gain intuition, let's study the corresponding system over $\mathbb R$.  Then we might as well assume $ad = 2013$.  Let $\epsilon \approx 0$, multiply $a$ by $1+\epsilon$, and $d$ by the corresponding factor $1-\epsilon$ (and ignore all factors of order $\epsilon^2$).  Then $d^2(2a-d)$ changes by $-d^2(2a-d)2\epsilon + d^2(2a\epsilon + d\epsilon) = \epsilon d^2(3d - 2a)$, up to order $\epsilon^2$.  The stationary point is therefore when $a = \frac32 d$.  If $a < \frac32 d$, increasing $a$ (i.e. setting $\epsilon>0$) increases the total.  If $a > \frac32 d$, decreasing $a$ (i.e. $\epsilon<0$) increases the total.  Thus the stationary point is the unique maximum.  Since $ad = 2013$, $d = \sqrt{\frac23\times 2013} \approx  36.63$, for a total of $d^2(2a-d) = 2d^3 = 2\times \left(\frac23\times 2013\right)^{3/2} \approx 98323$.

Second, suppose $3|d$, say $d = 3e$.  Then $3e^2 | (m-n) = 3e(a-b)$, so $e | (a-b)$.  We want to maximize $d^2(a+b) = 9e^2(a+b)$, subject to $e|(a-b)$, $1 \leq b < a$, and $ea \leq \frac{2013}3 = 671$.  Again we might as well make $b$ as large as possibly for a given fixed $a$, say $b = a-e$, and $a$ as large as possible for fixed $e$, say $a = \lfloor \frac{671}e \rfloor$.

Again switching to the real case, we have $ae = 671$ and we want to maximize $9e^2(2a - e)$.  We already decided this happens when $e = \frac23 a$, in which case $e = \sqrt{\frac23 \times 671} \approx 21.1$.  The real maximum here is $18\times \sqrt{\frac23 \times 671}^3 \approx 170301.8$.

How close to this can we get with integers?  Rounding $e$ to $21$ gives $a = \lfloor \frac{671}{21} \rfloor = 31$, hence $9e^2(2a - e) = 162729$.  In particular, this certainly does much better than the $3\!\!\not|\ d$ case.  Moreover, if $e\leq 17$ or $e \geq 25$, then $9e^2\left(2\frac{671}e-e\right) < 162729$.  So the only range we need to think about is $e=18,19,20,21,22,23,24$.  Why do we need all this range?  The function $e \mapsto 9e^2\left(2\frac{671}e-e\right)$ is pretty flat here (since $e\approx 21.1$ is a stationary point), so all the real values are close; so the winner will depend on how well $\lfloor \frac{671}e\rfloor$ approximates $\frac{671}e$.

For example, rounding $e$ to $22$ gives $a=30$ and $9e^2(2a - e) =165528$.  This rules out $e=24$ and $e=18$.  Trying $e=23$ gives $a=29$ and $9e^2(2a - e) = 166635$.  Finally, $e=20$ gives $a=33$ and and $9e^2(2a - e) = 165600$.  The winner is $166635$, at $m=3ea = 2001$ and $n=3e(a-e) = 414$.

I'm not sure how to do the last part without a calculator — I mean, in principal I know how to compute long square roots and of course to do the multiplications, but I wouldn't want to.

Comment: Oh, and I need to check that $a=29$ and $29-23=6$ are relatively prime.  They are.